# Learn python the hard way exercise52

Tags: python, web.py

I'm confused about the code in exercise 52.

```
if session.room and form.action:
    session.room = session.room.go(form.action)
```

I highlighted the code. I don't know why it needs this and why it cannot pass the test if I delete them.

```
import web
from gothonweb import map

urls = (
  '/game', 'GameEngine',
  '/', 'Index',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

# little hack so that debug mode works with sessions
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    store = web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
    session = web.session.Session(app, store,
                                  initializer={'room': None})
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")


class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        # this is used to "setup" the session with starting values
        session.room = map.START
        web.seeother("/game")


class GameEngine(object):

    def GET(self):
        if session.room:
            return render.show_room(room=session.room)
        else:
            # why is there here? do you need it?
            return render.you_died()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(action="None")

        # there is a bug here, can you fix it?
        if session.room and form.action:
            session.room = session.room.go(form.action)

        web.seeother("/game")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Can you add context? What is exercise 52 about?

Comment: This seems to be a simple checker like the one you use to check if you have enough permissions to access some path on server

Comment: @ForceBru, is there any reference? I want to learn more about this.

Comment: As far as I understand, if you remove this code, an unauthorized user will be able to perform this action. It's like `if password="root": do_some_stuff_belonging_to_root()`, to my mind.

Comment: @Jost, the whole exercise is a little complex, could u give me your mail address so that I can "add context"?